# How can I make the command "eclipse myprogram.c" work in terminal?

Tags: gnome-terminal, eclipse

As the title says how can I make that command work. I have eclipse installed in my /opt/ folder and I did make a destop file with:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Version=4.6
Name=Eclipse Neon C
GenericName=IDE
Comment=Eclipse Neon for c/c++ developers
Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse
Terminal=false
Icon=/opt/eclipse/icon.xpm
Type=Application
Categories=Utility;Application;
```

However whenever I type `eclipse myprogram.c`, I get the following error"

```
The program 'eclipse' is currrently not installed. You can install it by typing: 
sudo apt install eclipse-platform.
```

Comment: Thomas's answer is what you're looking for, alternatively you can provide full path to eclipse on command line, same as stated in the Exec= line. For example `/opt/eclipse/eclipse myprog.c`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `eclipse` binary, is what is executed on the command line.  Unlike the Desktop and Dash which can use application launchers, you have to make sure the binary is stored in your `PATH` variable in the command line.

If you want to make this usable **one-time**, then run `export PATH="/opt/eclipse:$PATH"`.

If you want this to work **perpetually** for the future, then we need to make sure every time the shell is opened yourself, and add the `/opt/eclipse` folder to your `PATH` so that `eclipse` is correctly interpreted by your terminal.  If you are running Bash, add it to `~/.bashrc`, run `source ~/.bashrc`, and then run your original command again:

```
export PATH="/opt/eclipse:$PATH"
```

Comment: Thanks for responding, but I am bit of a first time user for ubuntu. So like what do I type in the terminal step-by-step, because I have gotten no clue....

Answer (score -1):

If you drop your .desktop file into .local/share/applications, then the eclipse program will be found.

What I don't know is if you can pass it a parameter like myprogram.c, without modifying your exec line in your .desktop file. If it won't pass your myprogram.c parameter, you can try changing the exec line to "Exec=/opt/eclipse/eclipse $1", without the quotes, or maybe Exec="/opt/eclipse/eclipse $1" with the quotes, and see if that works. postnote: maybe the $1 should be %F.

If that doesn't work, maybe some other expert here can help more.

Cheers, Al